# Rails 5 - include nested associations not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two simple models:

1. note.rb

with

`:title -> string, :content -> string
has_and_belongs_to_many :tags, join_table: :tags_notes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags`

2. tag.rb

with

`:name -> string
has_and_belongs_to_many :notes, join_table: :tags_notes`

Both models are connected through `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship.
The association table is called `tags_notes` as indicated above.
Well, the problem I have here is, in my RESTful controller, to get notes, I have this:

GET `/api/notes`
This only returns Note objects:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "12231",
        "content": "121213"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "test",
        "content": "testtest"
    }
]
```

However, each note has `tags`, and I would like to dump those in the response as well, like this:

```
     [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "12231",
            "content": "121213",
            tags: [
              {
                 "name": "test",
                 "id": 1
              },
              { 
                ...
              } 
            ]

        },
         ...
    ]
```

In my controller, I've tried 
`Note.includes(:tags)`.

Current controller code:

 `def index
    notes = Note.includes(:tags)
    render json: notes, status: :ok
  end`

They only seem to return `notes`, without `tags`. Same is the case with `Note.eager_load(:tags)` What am I doing wrong? Cannot find enough documentation that will help me fix this issue.
If someone can help me with this I will be grateful.

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly after posting my question I found the answer myself. The `include` has to go in `render.`

So the controller code

```
  def index
    notes = Note.all
    render json: notes, :include => :tags, status: :ok
  end
```

Seems to do the trick!